# Can't get Android 2.3 to handle GZIp

Tags: java, android

Having some issue with Android 2.3 not picking up the `Content-Encoding` header from our server.

See http://pastebin.com/v0Jvn0nD for a comparison with `2.2` and `2.3`.

So, I am trying to get a workaround so Android can handle the GZIP, at the moment it just fails. Here is the connection logic:

Any help would be cool. Many thanks

```
URL test = null;

try {
    test = new URL(url);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                URLConnection connection = null;

                try {
                    connection = test.openConnection();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                InputStream stream = null;
                try {
                    stream = connection.getInputStream();
                    Log.d("HttpHelper","getContentEncoding: " + connection.getContentEncoding()); // RETURNING NULL ON 2.3
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if ("gzip".equals(connection.getContentEncoding())) { // NULL HERE ON 2.3
                    try {
                        stream = new GZIPInputStream(stream);
                        responseString = textHelper.getText(stream);
                        globallistener.onComplete(responseString);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```